# Java Android Iteration of JSON Array with keyless JSON objects

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

So I'd like to iterate over a JSON array with objects within it.
Ive tried doing my research but all them tutorials out there explain how to do it with keyed JSON objects.

The JSON array looks like so:

```
 items:[{i know}, {what you did} ,{last summer}]
```

Comment: your json is not valid , first of all please validate it

Comment: thats just a snippet of what i would like to obtain

Comment: @bpA, its the actual object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(string);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
        String array[] = new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            array[i] = String.valueOf(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```